# Which came first: "do much of anything" or "do much if anything"

Tags: history

I came across the following online:

> I'm not actually sure this project will do much if anything to help since ...

Since there are no commas, I first read it as

> I'm not actually sure this project will do much **of** anything to help since ...

Are these two phrases (do much of/if anything) approximately the same, or did one arise much earlier than the other?

Comment: They're syntactically and semantically different (effectively, *unconnected*) constructions. It's just happenstance that only one letter changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> much, if anything, to help

I added the commas, but it means that the project will not do much to help—*or* it might do nothing at all to help.

> much of anything to help

This simply means that the project will not do much to help.

It's only the first sentence that offers the possibility of no help whatsoever.

Sometimes, *a little help is better than none*. (At other times, *a little help* won't make a noticeable difference.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that there is any history on those phrases, but you seem to think they mean the same thing.  They don't.

> "I'm not actually sure this project will do much of anything..."

This means that the project will do very little.  It can also mean that maybe it will do much but not much of any one thing, like there are several things it will do, just not a lot of any particular thing.

> "I'm not actually sure this project will do much if anything..."

This means that the project will do very little and raises the distinct possibly that it will do absolutely nothing at all.